# Pandas Hierarchical MultiIndex: Concise way to use values from other levels in a row calc

Tags: python, pandas

Probably easiest to demonstrate in code.

Basically I have:

- A hierarchical dataframe. Something similar to:

```
level1 level2
root   child1      10      10
       child2      20      20
       child3      30      30
       child4      40      40
root2  child1     100     100
       child2     200     200
       child3     300     300
       child4     400     400
```

The real data is not massive, so manually mapping is feasible.

I would like to:

- create a new column.
- the values in that column are a function of:

  - another column value and;
  - another column value *in a different row*.

Unfortunately, the location of the different row in the real data isn't something easily predictable/ordered (so I do not think shift or rolling will work - even if you might be able to stretch one of those to work for this data.)

I have a working solution, but I'm really new to PD, and I'm not sure its as concise as it could be, nor as canonical as it should be. (maybe it is great, happy to know if that's the case.)

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = """
level1,level2,value1,value2
root,child1,10,10
root,child2,20,20
root,child3,30,30
root,child4,40,40
root2,child1,100,100
root2,child2,200,200
root2,child3,300,300
root2,child4,400,400
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), index_col=[0,1])

# We want the following result:
#level1,level2,value1,value2,desiredcol
#root,child1,10,10,(child4, value1) + (child1, value2)
#root,child2,10,10,(child1, value1) + (child2, value2)
#root,child3,10,10,(child2, value1) + (child3, value2)
#root,child4,10,10,(child4, value2)

# First - isolate the value1 column, and use unstack
# to flip the dimension columnwise. 
value1s = df[['value1']].unstack()
print('value1s unstacked:')
print(value1s)

# Copy the needed columns to the relevant mapped states.
value1s[('intermediate', 'child1')] = value1s[('value1', 'child4')]
value1s[('intermediate', 'child2')] = value1s[('value1', 'child1')]
value1s[('intermediate', 'child3')] = value1s[('value1', 'child2')]
value1s[('intermediate', 'child4')] = 0

# Get rid of the original values as they are still in df.
value1s = value1s.drop(columns=['value1'])
# Flip back to rows.
value1s = value1s.stack()
print(value1s)

df = df.join(value1s, how='inner')
# Now we can just row-wise sum the relevant columns.
df['desiredcol'] = df[['value2', 'intermediate']].sum(axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: Where is the logic for value 1. A shift of values except for the last so 1, 2, 3, 4 become 4, 1, 2, -? Maybe you can sort your dataframe to order rows?

Comment: I cannot. This is just example data. The real data cannot be pac-man shifted into a rolling order.